# Adding spans inside a paragraph creates empty spaces in between the words

Tags: css

I have a paragraph on my website and I want to create a span for each word but when I did it on the front there appeared lots of spaces between each word, is there a way around this?

For example

```
<p id="forpc"><span>From a young age, <span>both myself</span> and <span>those</span> around <span>me, believed</span> <span>that</span> <span>I would</span></p>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: no code equals no answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe want to tell us a bit more, like posting a bit of CSS of something ? Which navigator are you using also ? I paste you code on a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6hr8w9df/) and it doesn't seems to be spacier than it should be, what do you think ?

```
<p id="forpc"><span>From a young age, <span>both myself</span> and <span>those</span> around <span>me, believed</span> <span>that</span> <span>I would</span></p>
```

Comment: okay so i just found this silly thing in my sites css, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

span{
 font-size: 0.8em;
 font-family: 'Amatic SC', bold;
 padding-left: 2vh;
 padding-right: 2vh;
}